# How to make integer patterns?

Tags: python, sequence

I want to build a sequence pattern, for example i have numbers `1`, `2`, `3`.
`1` is first pattern, `2` is second, and `3` is third.

```
# Assign all patterns.
First = 1
Second = 2
Third = 3


# Make a loop
for x in xrange(1, 100):
    print(Second)
```

This would simply print second, but i want it to print the number after every `2` integers.

so for example:

```
1 
2 - This is pattern 2
3 
4 - This is pattern 2
5
6 - This is pattern 2
7
...
```

How could i achieve this sequence? so i can make integer patterns in loop, such as integer `2` and after every `2` integers it prints that pattern2 integer was returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xrange` has a step parameter. See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange).

```
for x in xrange(1, 100, 2):
    print(Second)
```

To print Pattern 1, 2 and 3 successively:

```
patterns = [First, Second, Third]
for x in xrange(1, 100):
    print(patterns[x % 3])
```

To print only Third:

```
for x in xrange(1, 100):
    if x % 3 == 0:
        print(Third)
```

Comment: Thanks! can i add more arguments? so i can make 2 steps. (`for x in xrange(1, 100, 2, 3):`)

Comment: Not sure what you mean with two steps... `xrange` expects only one integer as step argument.

Comment: @ShellRox What does that mean? Do you want to increment the value sometimes by `2` and other times by `3`? You should do that manually.

Comment: I want to create a specific pattern, so the program knows that 1 is pattern 1, 2 is pattern 2, and 3 is pattern 3, and print them in loop.

Comment: Worked fine, is it possible to also print a single one in the loop? so for example to use `Third` variable from patterns in boolean flag. something like : `if x == patterns[Third]`? @JacquesGaudin

Answer (score 2):

You need to add an `if statement` with a `modulo operator(%)` like this:

```
# Assign all patterns.
First = 1
Second = 2
Third = 3


# Make a loop
for x in xrange(1, 100):
    print x
    if x % 2 == 0:
        print(Second)
```

Comment: Thanks! there are only 2 patterns here, `1` & `2` is it possible to assign 3?

Comment: What do you mean? do you want to print 3 in each 3 steps? then you should add `if x % 3 == 0`

Comment: I tried it but program doesn't know that there is step 3, how can i assign it?

Comment: Come and join this chat so that I can help you. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python